# enabling 32 bit application result in w3wp.exe crash IIS 10

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, windows-server-2016, application-pool, iis-10

In my solution, I have three different projects including ASP.Net MVC, Class Library, and Web API.
The application works fine on local, but on the production server (Windows Server 2016) after setting "Enable 32-bit Applications = true" in Application Pool (it is a neccessary requirement), the project stopped working.
The following information in EventViewer is available:

> Description: Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version:
> 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899135 Faulting module name: clrjit.dll, version: 4.8.4180.0, time stamp: 0x5e7d1e02 Exception code: 0xc00000fd
> Fault offset: 0x00009865 Faulting process id: 0xc64 Faulting
> application start time: 0x01d665a86c307401 Faulting application path:
> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe Faulting module path:
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll Report Id:
> 751158e0-ba08-4f54-ba3c-699e0983a43d

What could be the main reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: `0xc00000fd` means stack overflow. So in your case, you have to debug further, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/find-solutions-faster-by-analyzing-crash-dumps-in-visual-studio/

Comment: You can create a new project, then set Enable 32-bit Applications = true, then check whether there is a crash, if there is, then there is a problem with your project, if not, then you can use the [DebugDiag tool](https://www.cantabilesoftware.com/support/DebugDiagTool) to view the information in the action type for unconfigured first chance exceptions.